# Where is the Convert annotation in objectbox-dart?

Tags: objectbox

For this code

```
@Convert(converter = PointConverter, dbType = String)
  Point? origo;
```

I get the

> Undefined name 'Convert' used as an annotation.
> Try defining the name or importing it from another library.dart(undefined_annotation)

linter error message. Is there no object convert method in objectbox-dart?

I tried this: https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/custom-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `@Convert` annotation as in ObjectBox-Java. In Dart, you can define your converter in-line, using a dart getter and setter. For example, something like this should create a string database field `dbPoint`, while skipping `point` because it has an unknown type.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart';

@Entity()
class SomeClass {
  int? id;

  Point<double>? point;
  
  String? get dbPoint => point == null ? null : '${point.x} ${point.y}';
  
  set dbPoint(String? value) {
    if (value == null) {
      point = null;
    } else {
      final components = value.split(' ');
      if (components.length != 2) {
        throw ArgumentError.value(value, 'value', "Given value doesn't look like a point representation");
      }
      point = Point(double.parse(components[0]), double.parse(components[1]));
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, this is just an example and you can use any conversion you want, to any type supported by ObjectBox. E.g. the above would be more efficient if it converted to a binary vector (`Uint8List`).

Comment: Now I understand why I couldn't define setter/getter in my class. :) Thanks!